# Attempting to see if my public IP has changed automatically with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script that checks my current public IP address to one that I've written in to see if it has changed. So far I've got this:

```
$NIP = "97.121.63.227"
$url = "http://checkip.dyndns.com"   
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$Ip = $webclient.DownloadString($url) 
$Ip2 = $Ip.ToString() 
$ip3 = $Ip2.Split(" ") 
$ip4 = $ip3[5] 
$ip5 = $ip4.replace("</body>","") 
$FinalIPAddress = $ip5.replace("</html>","") 
$Prod = $NIP.CompareTo($FinalIPAddress)
$Prod
```

Whenever I run it though, comes up

```
Missing property name after reference operator.
At line:1 char:17
```

Pretty new to PowerShell and have no idea what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use a regex to avoid multiple split and replace :

```
$NIP = "97.121.63.227"
$url = "http://checkip.dyndns.com"   
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$Ip = $webclient.DownloadString($url) 
$FinalIPAddress=[regex]::match($ip,"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b").Value
$NIP -eq $FinalIPAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce the error unfortunately. Perhaps set a breakpoint (F9) at the top line and step through (F10) the script to narrow in on the cause. The error message is pointing to line 1...did you include that line in your example?